# Space complexity of quantum algorithms for Subset sum

Tags: quantum-computing, exp-time-algorithms, space-complexity

As far as I can find there are several quantum algorithms for the Subset sum problem with $2^{n/3}$ running time. Is there an algorithm with $2^{n/3}$ running time that uses much less space?